# Display Keras graph in Tensorboard without using the callback in the fit method

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, tensorboard

Is it possible to display a Keras graph in Tensorboard without using the tensorboard callback in the fit method?

Is it possible to extract the graph from Keras and display the graph using the tensorflow FileWriter?
`tf.summary.FileWriter(logdir='logdir', graph=graph)`

I want to do this to check all the connections of this part of the graph are as expected (this model is part of a larger model that is far from finished).

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turned out to be very simple by extracting the Tensorflow graph from the backend and using the file writer.

```
import tensorflow as tf
# Used to get the graph
from tensorflow.python.keras import backend as K


tb_path = "logs/"

# Simple model to test the tensorboard plotting
model = SimpleModel(50, 20, 10).build_model()

# Get the sessions graph
graph = K.get_session().graph

# Display with the tensorflow file writer
writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(logdir=tb_path, graph=graph)
```